# Javascripts not working when <!doctype html> inserted in correct format

Tags: javascript, html

Im developing a web page and im using some javascripts on the pages to move some html elements, but i found that javascript code is not working when `<!doctype html>`
or any type of `<!doctype>` s added to the top of the page ! what is this error?

I search on google and i found `<!doctype html>` is the correct format even stackoverflow source code has it but when i used it javascripts not working but when it removed script working fine & html object is moving but my styles are gone away because of removing `<!doctype html>`

```
<!doctype html>   when this line removed it works(html element is moving)
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function scrollDiv(){
                  var obj = document.getElementById("movingDiv");
                  obj.style.left = 100;
                  obj.style.top = 10;
                  }

                document.onclick = scrollDiv;

    </script>
</head>
<body  class="body">
<div class="maindiv" id="mainDiv">
  <div class="html_js_code" style="text-align:center;">

  <div id="movingDiv" style="position:absolute;left:100pt;top:10pt;border:1px blue 

outset;width:160px;background-color:lightyellow;font-weight:bold;">Moving Div</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your logic, your way of thinking is good. Only the conclusion is wrong: the error must be in your Javascript code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without a doctype, the browser assumes that unlabelled lengths are in pixels. With a doctype, they require an explicit unit.

```
obj.style.left = "100px";
obj.style.top = "10px";
```

Comment: Yes it works! thanks dude. so every time when it comes with doctype i have to use pixes right? thank u very much.

Comment: @NaveenChamikaraGamage You always have to use pixels when it's appropriate. But when you don't specify doctype, browsers are more lenient.

Comment: there is another problem in my mind, can't i set body with and height to 90% when using this doctype?

Answer (score -1):

you also forgot to put the parenthesis at the end of the function you called. I'm also pretty sure you passed it incorrectly. I believe it should look like this:

```
document.onclick = scrollDiv();
```

or

```
document.onclick(scrollDiv());
```

Comment: No, it should not look like this. Please try it.