# Background-Position on HTML tag not working

Tags: html, css, xhtml, background, position

I'm following one tutorial on webdesign tutsplus, Final Page:
http://webdesigntutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/126_RibbonNavTutorial/code/demo_css_ribbon.html

I've completed everything but one problem is coming in **html** styling, you can see I've included height:100% , but in original tutorial there was not that line, if I remove that line then it's collapsing, but in original tutorial it's perfect, why so?

And also right now I've done height:100% then you can scroll at bottom and can see there's a margin left off at bottom, I want that image to stick at the very bottom of the page.

Please download image also so that you can try this code, here are the links of images:

http://webdesigntutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/126_RibbonNavTutorial/code/bottom_bg.jpg

http://webdesigntutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/126_RibbonNavTutorial/code/top_bg.png

**CodePen** = http://codepen.io/joe/full/xruKk

**jsFiddle** = http://jsfiddle.net/rssatnam/YekQe/embedded/result/

code :

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
html{
  background:#77d5fb url('bottom_bg.jpg') bottom center no-repeat;
  height:100%;
}
body{
  background:transparent url('top_bg.png') top center no-repeat;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  margin:0 0;
}
#container{
  width:900px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
#navBar{
  height:62px;
  background-color:#e5592e;
  margin:3em 0;
  position:relative;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
  box-shadow:0px 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
  -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
  -o-box-shadow:0px 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
  border-radius:3px;
  z-index:500;
}
#menu li{
  list-style-type:none;
  display:block;
  float:left;
  margin:1em 0.8em;
}
#menu li a{
  display:block;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#F0F0F0;
  font-size:1.6em;
  margin:0;
  line-height:28px;
  text-shadow:0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0,0, 0.5);
}
#menu li a:hover{
  /*transition:margin-top 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition:margin-top 0.3s;*/
  margin-top:2px;
}
#lt-corner{
  width:0px;
  height:0px;
  border:50px solid;
  border-color:#d9542b transparent transparent;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  top:1px;
  left:-50px;
}
#lb-corner{
  border:50px solid;
  border-color:transparent transparent #d9542b;
  width:0px;
  height:0px;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  top:-40px;
  left:-150px;
}
#rt-corner{
  width:0px;
  height:0px;
  border:50px solid;
  border-color:#d9542b transparent transparent;
  position:relative;
  float:right;
  top:-107px;
  right:-45px;
}
#rb-corner{
  border:50px solid;
  border-color:transparent transparent #d9542b;
  width:0px;
  height:0px;
  position:relative;
  float:right;
  top:-149px;
  right:-145px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="lt-corner"></div>
      <div id="lb-corner"></div>
        <div id="navBar">
            <ul id="menu">
                <li><a href="#">&#10029; Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">&#10029; About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">&#10029; Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">&#10029; Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="rt-corner"></div>
      <div id="rb-corner"></div>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: looks good from me, I mean there is a vertical scrollbar but I can't see a margin at the bottom in Safari and Firefox.

Comment: When I tried this in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryangates/3nWNw/) I wasn't able to reproduce the issue while commenting out the height: 100%;

Comment: please use image also then you'll be able to see margin at the bottom of the page, I've tested it in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: I've updated jsFiddle and codePen links in my post, please check at the bottom of the page there.

Comment: Alternately, view the jsFiddle without the **iframe** by using `/show/` path.  Remove `/show/` to get back to the jsFiddle Edit Screen. [**LINK**](http://jsfiddle.net/rssatnam/YekQe/show/)

Comment: Yes, I've tried that also, still the margin at the very bottom of the page is coming, The image is slightly upwards from the bottom , check this >> http://jsfiddle.net/rssatnam/YekQe/show/

Comment: What you're experiencing is a problem with collapsing margins (http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins); the top margin from `div#navBar` is pushing `body` down by 3em, since `body` must be `100%`, the page takes up the vertical space of `100% + 3em`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example: [JSbin](http://jsbin.com/welcome/72867/). Make sure to edit and play around with it.

Add `margin:0` and `padding:0` to `html` & `body` element. To remove the bottom `margin`, just remove the `height:100%` from the `body` element. So here's the basic CSS:

```
html,body{ 
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

html{
  background:#77d5fb url('http://i.imgur.com/xbMWo.jpg') bottom center no-repeat; 
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

body{
  background:transparent url('http://i.imgur.com/2NPJi.png') top center no-repeat; 
  width:100%;
}
```

Side Note: Be sure to mark as the answer, if it solves your problem.

Comment: Hey abdhoms, I've tried everything it's still not working.
It's working on JSbin because of DOCTYPE.
Try it locally it will work only if you'll not include DOCTYPE.
But if you include DOCTYPE then again the problem will come, STRANGE but what to do ?
It's DOCTYPE Bug lol

Comment: It's not really a bug. Happens to be an issue with styling heights/widths. See [this question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384336/javascripts-not-working-when-doctype-html-inserted-in-correct-format)

Yours can be solved by adding `height:100%` and `width:100%` to `html` in your css.

Comment: Try removing `height:100%` from `body` if there's a bottom margin. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Told you guys already it's solved.
It will work only if you'll not include DOCTYPE. But if you include DOCTYPE then again the problem will come.